# How to print device ID from Particle Photon and SparkFun OpenScale?

Tags: embedded

I am setting up sensors with the Particle Photon and the SparkFun OpenScale. I would like to identify them uniquely from the serial connection. At the moment, my code on the Particle Photon outputs:

```
timestamp,temperature,acceleration
```

and the OpenScale outputs this by default (I removed most of the fields):

```
weight,unit,raw measurement
```

I want to include the device ID in both of the feeds. Particle [published a way](https://community.particle.io/t/finding-your-device-id/26531) to query the device ID and I would like to print it from within the firmware code to the serial line. With OpenScale, it seems impossible given that it's not an option in the menu after pressing `x`.

Is it possible to print a device ID from either the Particle Photon or the SparkFun OpenScale?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Particle Community](https://community.particle.io/t/device-id-over-serial-line/52009) had the answer for the Particle Photon and pointed me to [the reference documentation](https://docs.particle.io/reference/device-os/firmware/photon/#deviceid-). This code works:

```c
void setup() {
    String id = System.deviceID();
    Particle.publish("start", id.c_str());
}

void loop() {
}
```

and I then see this event on [the Console](https://console.particle.io):

```
start   <device-ID>
```

For the SparkFun OpenScale, you could fork the firmware, which is [open source on Github](https://github.com/sparkfun/OpenScale) to include a unique identifier from [a serial number, an FTDI chip, etc.](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/279/how-can-i-get-a-unique-id-for-all-my-arduino-boards), and flash the modified firmware to the device over the serial line.